# remove string thant contains letters& numbers from array

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter

i am trying to remove variables thant contains both letters & numbers from a list.

i made this function but i get no result.

```
list=['MARC JOHNSON', '+555-555-5555', '+555-555-5555', '203 Street Address.', 'Your Town 10000', 'COMPANY NAME', 'URSLOGANHER']

def Filter(datalist):
    for val in datalist:
        r = re.search(pattern=" [0-9][a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[ 0-9]+[.]*", string=val).group()
        datalist.remove(val)
        return datalist
Filter(list)
```

i am looking for this output:

list = ['MARC JOHNSON', 'COMPANY NAME', 'URSLOGANHER']

Answer (score 1):

without even using regex, you can do it in just one line:

```
my_list = ['MARC JOHNSON', '+555-555-5555', '+555-555-5555', '203 Street Address.', 'Your Town 10000', 'COMPANY NAME', 'URSLOGANHER']

result = [x for x in my_list if not any(c.isdigit() for c in x)]

>>> result
['MARC JOHNSON', 'COMPANY NAME', 'URSLOGANHER']
```